# Should we necessarily make different services for different controllers in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have created an application that consumes REST services.

For every controller I have to use different REST service url.

Say for My Profile, I use `api/my-profile` while for User Preferences I use

`api/user-prefs`

So although I use `$http` service for accessing these resources,I kind of have created a separate service for My profile and User Preferences.

I want to know what's the best practice should I make a common service method that takes various kind of parameters and reuse it or should I continue creating separate services for different urls.

PS: There is modification in 70% of service urls that I access. Hence I have created separate Services. Also I made different methods so that when someone reads my controller there is no common/abstract method due to which the developer gets confused. He can understand by just looking at the name what data is being received by this service method.

Example:

```
//seperate service UserPreferenceService
var data=UserPreferenceService.getPrefDetails().then(function(){
..
});
```

AND

```
//seperate service MyProfileService
var data=MyProfileService.getProfileDetails().then(function(){
..
});
```

So, I just want to know is my current practice a good practice or should I make a simple function which handles all sorts of modifications required.

Also I keep in mind John Papa's instruction for not mentioning the resource url in controller,that is the controller should not know from where the resource is being accessed

I hope I have explained my question well.

Comment: Why not just create **one** service - `MyRestService` and have it call different methods - `MyRestService.getProfileDetails()` and `MyRestService.getPrefDetails()`

Comment: Yeah, but its a large application. And I use require JS to load services and controllers on run time. Which makes this Idea impractical since you need not require all methods for a particular page or unwanted methods for modules that are not applicable at that moment.

Comment: Can someone please suggest is my current practice good since I want my code to be readable and another developer  must not be confused on looking my code. Also I saw a video where John Papa once said that the controller must not be aware from where the data is being fetched. Hence I have to mention the url within the service and rest all modifications like parameters are given within the respective service used.

Comment: If the services also require associated logic then yes they should be separate, otherwise you're grouping functionality based on the REST aspect which is too generalised to be a good basis. Ideally imo you should create services that represent domain concepts or that group logic addressing a specific type of practical issue.